# update the profile and display the updated data in the input filed

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

**I am trying to fetch the data the first time and displaying it into the input field then updating the profile and again updating the state to display the updated data. This code is not working plz help me out.**
*There is any other way let me know Plz*
**I'm fetich data from express and using Axios. I am using two useEffect. If it can achieve using one useEffect plz let me know **

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import logo from '../../_assests/default/default-profile-img.png';
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Image } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { MdCameraEnhance } from 'react-icons/md';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { userUpdate, getUserData } from '../../actions/userUpdate.actions';


const UserGeneral = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const user = useSelector((state) => state.getUserData);//accessing user data from the store.
    const userUpdated = useSelector((state) => state.updatedUser);// accessing user data after updated the profile
    let userDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({
        userName: "",
        fName: "",
        lName: "",
        company: ""
    });
    const { _id } = userDetails;
    console.log("updated user", userUpdated);
    console.log("auth user", user);

    const onSubmitForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const payload = { ...inputValue, "userId": _id };
        dispatch(userUpdate(payload));
        // setInputValue({
        //     userName: "",
        //     fName: "",
        //     lName: "",
        //     company: ""
        // });

    };
    const handleInput = (e) => {
        const nameOfInput = e.target.name;
        const valueOfInput = e.target.value;
        setInputValue({ ...inputValue, [nameOfInput]: valueOfInput });
    }
    const handleReset = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setInputValue({
            userName: "",
            fName: "",
            lName: "",
            company: ""
        });
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setInputValue({
            userName: userUpdated.username,
            fName: userUpdated.firstName,
            lName: userUpdated.lastName,
            company: userUpdated.company
        });
    }, [userUpdated]);
    const fetchUserData = () => {
        return dispatch(getUserData(_id)) /**/calling the action to get data in the state getUserData;**
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUserData();
        setInputValue({  //**here username and firstName, lastName, company getting undefined. only this part has error other is working.**
            userName: user.user.username,
            fName: user.user.firstName,
            lName: user.user.lastName,
            company: user.user.company
        });

    },[]);

    return (
        <>
            <Form onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
                <div className="text-center">
                    <div className="outer-div">
                        <Image src={logo} alt="" className="ui-w-80" thumbnail />
                        <label className="btn btn-outline-primary inside-div-label">
                            <input type="file" className="account-settings-fileinput" />
                            <MdCameraEnhance className="md-user-camera" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="media-body ml-4">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-default md-btn-flat">Reset</button>
                        <div className="text-gray small mt-1">Allowed JPG, GIF or PNG. Max size of 800K</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr className="border-light m-0" />


                <div className="card-body">
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicUserName">
                        <Form.Label>UserName</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Username" onChange={handleInput} value={inputValue.userName} />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="fromBasicFirstName">
                        <Form.Label>First Name</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="text" name="fName" placeholder="First Name" onChange={handleInput} value={inputValue.fName} />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="fromBasicLastName">
                        <Form.Label>Last Name</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="text" name="lName" placeholder="Last Name" onChange={handleInput} value={inputValue.lName} />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="fromBasicEmail">
                        <Form.Label>Company</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company" onChange={handleInput} value={inputValue.company} />
                    </Form.Group>
                </div>
                <div className="button-align-gap mt-3">
                    <Button type="submit">Save</Button>
                    <Button onClick={handleReset} variant="outline-secondary">Reset</Button>
                </div>
            </Form>
        </>
    )
}

export default UserGeneral
```